# How can I improve this jQuery statement?

Tags: jquery

Is there a better way to write this:

```
$('.kog td:nth-child(8), .kog th:nth-child(8)').show();
```

I am repeating the class selector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
$('.kog').find('td,th').filter(':nth-child(8)').show();
```

You'll notice it isn't more succinct but it probably better shows your intent.

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the variable and find what you want within it. I'd personally use a class to set the visibility.

```
var $kog = $( '.kog' );

$kog.find( 'td:nth-child(8), th:nth-child(8)' ).addClass( 'is-visible' );
```

So then you would have a CSS class like this:

```
.is-visible { display: block; }
```

You may have to specify the rule as !important if it conflicts with whatever else you have going on.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML or knowing your use case, it's tough to say.

Is `.kod` going to return multiple tables? If so, you might show things you might not intend to show. If there are two `.kod` tables, and they have 6 TD each, you'll show things in the 2nd table. Ditto for your TH selector.

This seems a rather odd selector / thing to do; Is this a single, long table with only a header and one body row? If so, then I guess what you are doing makes sense, and you could avoid repeating the class selector by doing this:

```
jQuery('.kod').find("td:nth-child(8), th:nth-child(8)").show();
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/n2dGm/